# Wireless extremely slow on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 about a month ago.

Since then my internet connectivity has been extremely slow. I am connected using WiFi and I have a Intel wireless 7260 network card. Webpages take forever to load. Other devices connected to the same network have no problem at all and my Windows installation does not either. I have been browsing the Ubuntu forums for a while now and have tried a lot of different things such as disabling ipv6 but to no avail.

Edit: As requested:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf    
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` to your question

Comment: Hey, updated the questions as you asked.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the results of `iwlist scan` for your access point to look for TKIP as it will reduce download speed and try `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and reboot

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1319630 is a bug report that says that performance dropped 85% without using the `11n_disable=8` parameter

EDIT: You may also see improvement by setting your country code with

```
sudo iw reg set CA
```

And by editing the crda file `gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda` and change the line that is usually `REGDOMAIN=00` to `REGDOMAIN=CA` then save and exit program, reboot

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ran the command and it doesn't seem to end. I read the thread for the bug report and someone mentioned that to make it permanent I had to add a new file? Internet seems to have gotten better after I ran it, but will only find out if I use it for a few more hours. How would I go about making it permanent if it did end up making a difference?

Comment: It is permanent with the method I instructed you to use, but it can be removed if needed.  The non-permanent method is `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` followed by `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` as it will have no effect after a reboot or even after `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` followed by `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`  If you want to look at the entire results of `iwlist scan` run it this way `iwlist scan > iwlist.txt` and you should be able to look at the entire file with `gedit iwlist.txt`

Comment: Alright thanks. Just fyi, I had to end the command with Ctrl + C as it would not end by itself. Is this normal?

Comment: There must be a lot of wifi access points in your area if that is the case, the alternative is the wireless script from ubuntuforums http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108 and you can paste the contents of wireless-info.txt at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL it shows

Comment: Here is the info from the file after running the script. http://paste.ubuntu.com/10545472/

Comment: I just notice I missed a quotation mark in the code in my answer, I just edited it. `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disabled=8" sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Comment: Ah! There we go. Command worked right away. I will update after a bit and see how much difference it made. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not make much difference =/ I think I am going to go ahead and uninstall Ubuntu and maybe switch to Linux Mint. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't do that quite yet.  I have another idea but I need to get on one of my pc's

Comment: Alright. I will hold off on that. Really appreciate the time you are putting in to help me out! Good news is that it does seemed to have gotten slight better :)